# Basisc DIY bluetooth detection device

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, openframeworks

I am looking to make a simple, small device, that is picked up by a computer when turned on.

Specifics: I am looking on making modified glasses that whenever an user puts them on, they are "activated". I am thinking a pseudo-beacon system may work, but do not wish to use Arduino or other microprocessors, as the glasses should not be heavily modified. The idea would be a simple switch which powers a bluetooth signal that can be picked up by a computer, and furthermore, connected to openFrameworks. The architecture should be as simple as a bluetooth emitter, a switch and power. Is this possible?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Ironic how you disable saying "thanks", but do take the time to correct my non-native english. I would express my gratitude but I guess I am not allowed.

Comment: Correcting spelling and grammar is one of the things one should do when editing.

Answer (score 0):

A device like http://bleduino.cc/ might be your best best for size and ease of development, though it may be hard to get hold of.

Another bigger device: http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/bleduino-ble-for-arduino-p-788.html

You could get this and hook it up to a small arduino: http://www.dx.com/p/jy-mcu-arduino-bluetooth-wireless-serial-port-module-104299#.VTWERPmUdSE

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

http://www.rfduino.com/product/rfd22102-rfduino-dip/index.html

http://femto.io/

They are based on Arduino, but prove useful tanks to their extra small size.